# Is it possible to start barcode scanning from python on a barcode scanner?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have a [barcode scanner](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/scanners/general-purpose-scanners/handheld/ds4308.html), and currently, it is working as a keyboard so if the scanner successfully scans by pushing the trigger the scanned code goes to the computer as input.

Now, I want to write a python program on my Raspberry Pi 3B which connects to the scanner and start the scanning process without the need of pushing the trigger on the scanner. Meaning that I make a GUI where only by just clicking on a button the user starts the scanning process and the scanned code (if the scan was successful) gets outputted.

The question is: how to do it?

I have tried [pyusb](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb) but it can't send a ***command*** to the scanner to scan (Or I don't know how).

Even worse if it turned out that there is nothing like Python-Scanner communication, only the primitive `connected || not connected` type.

Comment: has the scanner software api a way to programmatically start a scan process?

Comment: I don't know, the [manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/barcode-scanners/ls2208-product-reference-guide-en-us.pdf) says that I can set the scanner from default keyboard mode to "Simple COM Port Emulation", maybe that means something more usefull for a python program, but I don't know how this Simple COM Port Emulation can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which operating system you use, you should look into the SDKs for the scanner you're using. It seems they provide some tools to control the scanner. They a re not very informative on what exactly they support though. ( for example: https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/scanner-sdk-for-linux.html)

The reference manual for the serial interface I found here:
https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/barcode-scanners/Simple%20Serial%20Interface%20Programmer's%20Guide.pdf

Comment: This might be useful, I will try it.